# enough plus that-clause

Tags: vocabulary, clauses

> Eve and Denny were in love with the place. They spent almost the entire first night there rolling around naked in every room except Zoe’s. When Denny came home from work, he would first say hello to the girls, then he would take me outside to the yard and throw the ball, which I happily retrieved. And then Zoe got big **enough that** she would run around and squeal while I pretended to chase her. And Eve would admonish her: “Don’t run like that; Enzo will bite you.”
>
> (Garth Stein, The Art of Racing in the Rain)

When *that*-clause follows *enough*, the clauses seem to have either showing the result or the degree of *enough*. Is it a matter of contexts or is there any rule for *enough that*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no rule of putting *that* after *enough*. It can have *to* as well. See this -

> A man must be big enough to admit his mistakes, smart enough to profit from them, and strong enough to correct them - *John C. Maxwell*

Putting *to* might show the capability, the degree of enough etc. as in the case I mentioned above. Putting *that* after *enough* generally talks about the *result* and so is in the case you presented.